# Android: Enable / Disable a button in Runtime?

Tags: android, button, runtime

Ok, so I have two buttons. The first one is to "Load Text" and the second is to "Speak Out".

Now, I don't want the Speak button to be active while there is no text loaded.

I've managed to set value into the EditText by Load Text button's onClickListener method. Inside the same method I have called,

```
btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
```

I have initialized this as,

```
btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

The entire coding is,

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
        || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            //for checking
            if(btnSpeak.isEnabled())
            {
                Toast.makeText(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.this, "Button should work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.this, "Button should not work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }

}
```

This is to check the status and assign language to the TTS for further use. I get the toast as "Button should work" but it doesn't get enabled. Why is it so? What's the work around?

I have in .xml file as,

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="@string/tts_text" />
```

Should I have it enabled in here and then disable and enable in runtime??

Comment: check whether you initialized the button with correct id

Comment: Yes, I have with the correct id.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
        || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            //for checking
            if(btnSpeak.isEnabled())
            {
                btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        YourVoicemethod();

                        Toast.makeText(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.this, "Button should work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                });
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.this, "Button should not work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. If I leave all this out and have both the buttons enabled, when I click on second button I don't get the sound, why would that be?

Comment: where is button onclick methd?

Answer (score 9):

You have to use `setClickable`

```
btnSpeak.setClickable(true);
btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
```

Also, use `isEnabled()` to check the state

```
//for checking
if(btnSpeak.isEnabled())
{
  Toast.makeText(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.this, "Button should work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
  Toast.makeText(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.this, "Button should not work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have used isEnabled, made a mistake while checking it in here. Will try with clickable though.

Comment: use setFocusuble(true) and setFocusubleInTouchmode(true)

Comment: Yes! This is the right answer (both, clickable and enabled events must be handled). Thank you @ling.s

Answer (score 5):

Check your button is pressed or not and write your code.

Sample code.

```
if(button2.isPressed()){
    button2.setEnabled(false);
    button1.setEnabled(true);
}
else if(button1.isPressed()){
    button1.setEnabled(false);
    button2.setEnabled(true);
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

May be is too late to answer and you already found a solution, but you can use invalidate to force the button to redraw itself according to its new state:

```
btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
btnSpeak.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve by disable and enabling the visibility of button

here is an example

```
View button = findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Although I still wonder why would Enabled not work in runtime, if I don't get any possible solution to that I'd select yours as the answer. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Use one listener for both buttons

```
button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
button2.setOnClickListener(listener);

listener = new OnClickListener({
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(button_id){
            case id1:
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            button1.setEnabled(true);
            break;
            case id2:
            button1.setEnabled(false);
            button2.setEnabled(true);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```